# snakemake rule with conda

Tags: conda, snakemake

I want to run a shell command via snakemake within a conda environment in a podman-container.

The snakefile looks like this:

```
rule download:
    output:
        "out/SRR12346784.fastq"
    conda: 
        "/home/keks/app/conda_env.yml"
    shell:
        """
        fasterq-dump --split-files --outdir out SRR12346784
        """
```

and the conda yaml file like this:

```
channels:
  - bioconda
dependencies:
  - sra-tools
```

However, snakemake response with:

```
/bin/sh: 1: source: not found
/bin/sh: 2: fasterq-dump: not found
```

and consequently gets an error after this, not being able to execute the fasterq-dump command.

When i enter the created conda environment outside of snakemake, everything works fine

```
conda activate /home/keks/app/.snakemake/conda/6a57ef84/
fasterq-dump --split-files --outdir test SRR12346784
```

Comment: How are you running that workflow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution.

As the `/bin/sh: 1: source: not found` suggests, is the snakemake script executing another shell. this can be fixed by adding  `shell.executable('/bin/bash')` at the beginning of the snakefile.